# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\DBtest\sqlsrv.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} SQLSERVER

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlsrv

Error problem:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
> sqlsrv_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\DBtest\sqlsrv.php:7 Stack trace:
> #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\DBtest\sqlsrv.php on line 7

PHP for testing connection:

```
<?php
$serverName = "LAPTOP-NUUM4IGR\SQLEXPRESS"; //serverName\instanceName

// Since UID and PWD are not specified in the $connectionInfo array,
// The connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication.
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"perkuliahan");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

PHP.ini file:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64.dll 
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll 
extension=php_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64.dll 
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll
```

pdo_sqlsrv on my phpinfo appears well. extension Ver 5.8.0 + 12928
I have installed ODBC
PHP Version 7.4.10

Previously I used SQL SERVER 2008 R2, I guess that is not eligible so I upgraded to SQL Server 2012. But still stuck
there was a mistake I did? I am very grateful for your solution.

Comment: You need to enable the `sqlsrv` part of the driver, using the appropriate extension. My guess is, that you need to add `php_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll` (thread-safety version).

Answer (score 0):

The MSSQL extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later. SQLSRV, an alternative driver for MS SQL is available from Microsoft:

» http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

> 1.Download SQLSRV32.EXE (Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server) from: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098
>
> 2.Choose path: C:\xampp\php\ext
>
> 3.Uncomment or Append extension = php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll in php.ini
>
> 4.Restart Apache from XAMPP Control Panel (Stop/Start)

I tested it and it works 100%

Comment: it says the procedure entry point _zval_ptr_dtor could not be located in the dynamic link library when i try to restart apache

Comment: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/procedure-entry-point-could-not-be-located-in-the-dynamic-link-library

Comment: check this solution for this